# SummarizeColumns() and AddMissingItems() Error On Weighted Average Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I pierced a very small portion of the Contoso data model and from there I created this calculated table:

```
CT Price Var Analysis = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
    DimProduct[Product], 
    "Sales Quantity, Weight", [Sales Quantity, Weight], 
    "Avg Sale Price % Var", [Avg Sale Price % Var] 
)
```

[image]

I then needed to calculate the weighed total of 'Avg Sale Price % Var' (basically the Excel equivalent of a SUMPRODUCT of both columns out of the aforementioned calculated table), and for that I wrote the following measure:

```
Avg Sale Price % Var, Annual Total = 
IF( 
    NOT ISBLANK ( [Sales Quantity, Weight] ) && 
    NOT ISBLANK ( [Avg Sale Price % Var] ), 
    SUMX( 
        'CT Price Var Analysis', 
        'CT Price Var Analysis'[Sales Quantity, Weight] * 'CT Price Var Analysis'[Avg Sale Price % Var] 
    ) 
)
```

And that worked just fine...

However, I wanted to bypass the creation of the calculated table altogether by embedding its code into the measure, so I tried this:

```
Avg Sale Price % Var, Annual Total (no CT) = 
VAR QtyWeight = [Sales Quantity, Weight]
VAR ASPVar = [Avg Sale Price % Var]
VAR Result = 
    IF( 
        NOT ISBLANK ( QtyWeight ) && 
        NOT ISBLANK ( ASPVar ), 
        VAR QtyWeightASPVarTable = 
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
                DimProduct[Product], 
                "@QtyWeight", QtyWeight, 
                "@ASPVar", ASPVar 
            )
        VAR Result = 
            SUMX( 
                QtyWeightASPVarTable, 
                [@QtyWeight] * [@ASPVar] 
            )
        RETURN
            Result
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

But I keep getting the error: **"SummarizeColumns() and AddMissingItems() may not be used in this context."**

Does that mean I cannot use SUMMARIZECOLUMNS in such instance? What should I use then? Or in such case I just have to go with this intermediary calculated table?

Any help on this would greatly expand my currently limited knowledge of DAX code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUMX( 
    ALL(DimProduct[Product]),
    [Sales Quantity, Weight] * [Avg Sale Price % Var]
)
```

This will give you the weighted average of `[Avg Sale Price % Var]` by `[Sales Quantity, Weight]`, assuming that `[Sales Quantity, Weight]` always sums to 1. If this can't be assumed, be sure to wrap this in a division by the sum of `[Sales Quantity, Weight]` like so:

```
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX( 
            DimProduct[Product]),
            [Sales Quantity, Weight] * [Avg Sale Price % Var]
        ),
        [Sales Quantity, Weight]
    ),
    ALL(DimProduct)
)
```

Note, in both examples I assumed this measure is to always be calculated over the entire `DimProduct` table. If this is not the case, simply exclude the `ALL()` filter from the latter to dynamically calculate weighted average over selected products.

```
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX( 
            DimProduct[Product]),
            [Sales Quantity, Weight] * [Avg Sale Price % Var]
        ),
        [Sales Quantity, Weight]
    )
```

Comment: Much easier than I had anticipated! Thanks a lot!